# Difference between "was settled" and "settled"

Tags: past-tense, reflexive-pronouns

I am really confused between these 2 sentences:

> He *settled* himself in London.
> He *was settled* in London.

Do they convey exactly same meaning? And why do we need reflexive pronoun in the first one but not in the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To settle oneself somewhere is to take up residence in that place, with the intention of remaining there for more than a short time. To be settled somewhere is to have previously done that. The first refers to an act, the second to a state.